# Line estimation between two points on a graph VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

My problem is this: I process data in an excel macro, this process generates charts and makes it possible to select two points on one of the charts.

I'm picking up the index of the selected points and storing them in variables. I would like to know if it is possible to make a linear regression line in order to regain the direct coefficients of the regression line between these two points.

Comment: Are you looking for the [LINEST function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84D7D0D9-6E50-4101-977A-FA7ABF772B6D)?

Comment: Yes but i don't know how to make it work between my two points

Comment: Can you recuperate the `Range` of values between those two points?

Comment: If i can get the x value of this point yes i will look at the data sheet and it will be good. But can i get the coordinates of the point because i have only the index of the point ?

Comment: I think so, since you know the range from which you created the series in the graph

Comment: I can t find out how to get the coordinates of the the point. It s something like ...serieCollection(1).Points(X).x i guess

Comment: I really don't understand the reason of closing this question !? (@Mat'sMug & other guys). Too broad? not at all, it is very specific and the problem is stated clearly.

Comment: @A.S.H too broad, indeed - at face value the question has a yes/no answer ("is it possible to..."), and IMO while the problem is stated clearly indeed, the OP's attempts aren't. I don't see how it's very much different from other "how do I do X?" questions that describe exactly what they need.. which routinely get closed as *too broad*.

Comment: @Mat'sMug you're probably right, just a bit disappointed that the problem seemed interesting to me and took me some amount of time to answer.

Comment: @A.S.H eh, *too broad* questions often demand a significan amount of effort to answer... OP can still mark it as *accepted*, and you got my upvote =)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I could guess that, thanks :). My disappointment was more related to the *originality* (to my own taste) of the question itself and its potential usefulness. But I don't oppose the reason of closing anymore, it was "on the edge" of having this fate, in the best case.

Comment: I found a solution : I used the Arg2 parameter of the select event on the chart. It returned me the X value of the point. Thank's to everyone

Comment: Ooops, we thought you already did that! *"Je récupère donc l'index des points et les stoque dans des variables"*.. .*"J'aimerai savoir s'il est possible de faire une droite de régression lineaire"*.Do you think that your comment above answers your initial question???

Comment: I was able to get the index of the point in the serie but not the x value but as I said before i fixed it this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function calculates the least-squares line given two points on a series in a chart object.

```
' Calculates the "a" and "b" of the least squares line
' given a series and two indexes on the series
' returns an array(1 to 2) where a is (1) and b is (2)
Function linest(s As Series, idx1 As Long, idx2 As Long)
    ReDim Xs(idx1 To idx2) ' The X values
    ReDim Ys(idx1 To idx2) ' The Y values
    Dim i As Long
    For i = idx1 To idx2
        Xs(i) = s.XValues(i)
        Ys(i) = s.values(i)
    Next
    linest = WorksheetFunction.linest(Ys, Xs)
End Function
```

**Usage**

This test creates a chart from sheet1 columns A (X's) and B (Y's).
Then it calculates, using the function above, the least-squares line for the values between the 5th and the 15th points.

```
Sub Test()
    ' first let us create a chart object and a series
    Dim ch As ChartObject, s As Series
    Set ch = Sheet1.ChartObjects.Add(10, 10, 500, 250)
    Set s = ch.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    s.XValues = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")
    s.values = Sheet1.Range("B1:B20")

    ' calculate the least-squares line between 5th and 15th points
    Dim eq: eq = linest(s, 5, 15)

    ' display the results
    Debug.Print " The least squares line is:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                " Y = " & eq(1) & "*X + " & eq(2)
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow morning and will tell you about that. Thank's a lot for trying to fix my problem (and sorry for my english)

Comment: Thank's for the help

Comment: @K.Fanedoul You are welcome.